# Take limit of an Integral (both the limit and the function inside)

Tags: integration, limits, functions

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \int\limits_a^{bn} {{f_n}(x)g(x)dx} $$

I am stuck now,
but I can show f_n is bounded in the region (a,bn)
I tried to to this but I have no idea if this is valid or not.

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } \int\limits_a^k {{f_\infty }(x)g(x)dx} $$

Please Help!

Comment: What do we know about f and g?  And what kind of integral is this -- Riemann or Lebesgue? Switching limits has certain requirements  for example uniform convergence (Riemann).

Comment: indeed I am working a m.g.f of a random variable, where the range depends on n and f_n being the p.d.f and g being e^(tx)

Comment: and here i am just trying to find a limit funtion of the m.g.f as n goes to infinity, and also find a range for t such that this limit exist. If i can take the limit for f_n first, I can work out the limiting p.d.f and by calculating the integral, i can tell what values of t make this limit exist. But taking limits at different stages do not looks legit to me...:(

Answer (score 0):

You certainly need some assumptions to get this to converge.  The most likely to work may be the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: actually this integral is a moment generating function of a random variable, and that random variable depends on others random variables which got a range (a,bn). which makes this integral has n on its limit and within the integral.
Does this help..?

Comment: Not really.  Why don't you tell us the actual integral?